# Data binding not happening in the child component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to load a child component from the parent component. From the parent component I need to pass some parameter to the child which would be used in the child component to make a service call and retrieve some data from WebAPI Service. the returned data should be bound to some input controls in the child component.

I validated that the parameter is passed to the child component and it makes the service calls and returns back with the data properly. but the returned data is not bound with the input controls in the child component.

Note: Making the WebAPI service call and retrieving the data is written in a public method of the child component, this method is invoked from the parent component after assigning/passing the input parameter.

my parameter component invocation method

```
this._cr.resolveComponent(ExtractorQueueDetails).then(cmpFactory => {
                if (this.cmpRef) {
                    this.cmpRef.destroy();
                    this.cmpRef = null;
                }
                console.log("Creating ExtractorQueueDetails component");

                this.cmpRef = this.childContainer.createComponent(cmpFactory);
                this.cmpRef.instance.ExtractorQueueID = this.extractorQueueID;
                this.cmpRef.instance.LoadExtractorQueueDetails();//public method in child component

            });
```

Parent component html content

```
<div>
    <k-grid [options]="options" (click)="onChange($event)"></k-grid>
</div>
<div>
    <extractorqueue-details [(ngModel)]="resultData"></extractorqueue-details>
</div>
```

my child component

```
import { Component, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CacheDataService } from '../Service/CacheDataService';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'extractorqueue-details',
    templateUrl: './HTML/Admin/ExtractorQueueDetails.html',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [CacheDataService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})
export class ExtractorQueueDetails {
    @Input() ExtractorQueueID : any; 
    resultData: any;

    constructor(private _CacheDataService: CacheDataService) {
        console.log("ExtractorQueueDetails component is loaded");
        console.log("ExtractorQueueID received : " + this.ExtractorQueueID);

        if (this.ExtractorQueueID != undefined) {
            this.LoadExtractorQueueDetails();
        }
    }

    GetExtractorQueuesByID(_extractorQueueID) {
        console.log("Inside GetExtractorQueuesByID method in ExtractorQueueDetails");

        this._CacheDataService.GetExtractorQueuesByID(_extractorQueueID)
            .subscribe(
            (res) => {
                this.resultData = res;
                console.log(this.resultData);
                //this.DrawBubbleChart();
            },
            (error) => console.log(error),
            () => console.log('Error in GetExtractorQueuesByID in ExtractorQueueDetails')
            );
    }

    public LoadExtractorQueueDetails()
    {
        console.log("in sample of ExtractorQueueDetails");
        console.log("ExtractorQueueID received in sample : " + this.ExtractorQueueID);

        this.GetExtractorQueuesByID(this.ExtractorQueueID);
    }
}
```

my child component html contents

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                    <label>Queue ID</label>
                    <input type="text" name="txtQueueID" class="form-control" id="txtQueueID" [(ngModel)]="resultData.queueId">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                    <label>Current Status</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" id="" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                    <label>Application</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="resultData.Description" id="" value="">

                </div>
```

**Edited: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xROfBv?p=preview) with hardcoded json data**

I have created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xROfBv?p=preview) where I tried to hard code the json and bind it to the textbox control. But it is not working here

Comment: Why do you put `value={{resultData.queueId}}` isn't `ngModel` enough to bind?

Comment: it should be, just tried it with that as well. still it is not working...any other issues in my code? when is the html binding would happen? my understanding is after I call my public method in the child component then it is going to happen? correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: I suggest you hard code a json response to resultData and see if it binds or not

Comment: @AngJobs: tried in plunker with hardcoded json data, but it doesn't work there also (not sure about the mistake I am doing here). Please correct me if you have any ideas

Comment: Ok, I recommend simplifying your main question then, remove the webapi stuff. I am sure somebody else would notice the issue.